# Visualforce Email Template Related Info

Tags: visualforce, email-template, approval-process, visualforce-template

I have a template for a Custom Object Business_Trip__c with Child relationship to Event via Custom Lookup.
I want to show related meetings.

Template below:

```
<p><b>Planned Meetings:</b></p>
<table border="1" >

    <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Meetings__r}">
        <tr>
             <td>Name: {!cx.WhoId}</td>
             <td>Date: {!cx.ActivityDate}</td>
             <td>Company: {!cx.Whatid}</td>
             <td>Subject: {!cx.Subject}</td>
             <td>Notes: {!cx.Comments_Summary__c}</td>
        </tr>

    </apex:repeat>                 
</table>
<p />
```

Provides indecipherable results:

Planned Meetings:
**Name: 003J000001EWnkiIAD**    Date: Thu Jul 09 00:00:00 GMT 2015  **Company: 001J000001btDA7IAM** Subject: Quarter review

When what I want is:

**Name: Joe Conact** Date: Thu Jul 09 00:00:00 GMT 2015 **Company: AcmeWidgetCo**. Subject: Quarter review

How do I get the names - the Contact and Account names -  from the relation? thanks!

I have tried:

Name: {!cx.Who} - Causes big error on test send

Name: {!cx.WhoId.name} - gets Error: Unknown property 'String.name'

Name: {!cx.WhoId__r.name}

and
Name: {!cx.Who__r.name}

Both get -  Error: Invalid field WhoId__r for SObject LookedUpFromActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`WhoId`** is a polymorphic field in `Event` Object which can point to `Contact` or `Lead`.

So just like `AccountId` in `Contact` Object where you can use `Contact.Account.Name`, you can use `Who.Name` to retrieve the Name of `Contact` or `Lead` associated with the `Event`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I tried many iterations, but who.name and what.name weren't it. thanks - helps me understand better.